# Occupancy grid mapping for beginner

Tags: ros, occupancy-grid, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am a beginner in the field of localization and mapping for mobile robots and I am a little confused right now.

What am I basically trying to do is to implement some occupancy grid mapping algorithm that uses only data from laser range finder sensor on mobile robot and uses some kind of probabilistic approach.

Trying to find one of those existing algorithms I just feel overwhelmed with information about theory but not actual implementation, which could help me to understand. Especially with all probabilistic models I don't seem to quite understand why it should work or how to imagine it.

Can you suggest any implementations or maybe some articles about this problematic, or maybe some advice?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223426/occupancy-grid-mapping-for-beginner/) by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 826 on 2016-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try understanding the theory, there are many papers out there for different algorithms.
One example package is [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping)  by the University of Freiburg.
On the [external documentation](http://openslam.org/gmapping.html) are some links to papers regarding this implementation.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0